# Javascript KeyboardEvent CTRL + ALT + KEY shortcut. Event.key is not KEY but special char

Tags: javascript, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-events

I have an application with shortcuts. Shortcuts are defined by the keys that need to be pressed to trigger them and the respective action that should happen.

When pressing CTRL + ALT + e on the keyboard, the triggered keydown KeyboardEvent.key value is not "e" but "€", because CTRL + ALT + e also is the combination for the € char.

So I cant define the shortcut as CTRL + ALT + e.

Should I define it as CTRL + ALT + € instead? This seems somewhat hacky to me, bc pressing CTRL + ALT + e won't result in € on all machines.

I thought about using the KeyboardEvent.code instead of KeyboardEvent.key. But the way I understood it, the KeyboradEvent.code is dependent on the keyboard layout. It should always be the letter 'e' though.

Any idea how i can still define the shortcut as CTRL + ALT + e? (it is a graph drawing application, and 'e' stands for edge, using any other letter would be unfortunate)

Answer (score -1):

it does work but you still have to cumulate to the other conditions for non-OSX users...

```
if (event.altKey && e.key === "€" || event.altKey && e.key === "e"){
   doSomeThing()
}
```